# Bootstrap Dropdown with Input inside Table Head Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I want one of the `<th></th>` in my table to be a link displaying a drop-down when clicked. I also want an input field with a filter button placed to the right in the same drop-down.

```
                <th>
                    <div class="dropdown inline-dropdown input-dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <span>Name</span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu input-dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <input class="pull-left input-first" type="text"/>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Filter</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </th>
```

Please see my fiddle for more clarification.

Old:
<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/qeT6T/19/</strike>

Updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/qeT6T/47/

Comment: In 2012, you should not be using tables for layout. 2013 I doubt will be any different. `:)` Welcome to SO.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Um, this isn't for "layout" and I'm well aware that it's 2012, soon to be 2013. I am using tables for tabular data, not my page structure. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you remove all of your style definitions you've added, it stops wrapping. One suggestion I would have initially is not to use margins on the input and button, and use padding instead on the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `white-space: nowrap` on the dropdown's `li`:

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qeT6T/55/

Comment: I updated my question. I removed that line but the problem persist.

Comment: jsFiddle is being ornery and not responding at the moment, but note that you *do* need to make the dropdown itself a certain size. Otherwise, it sizes to the width of the `th` that contains it, and you have to make the `th` width wider (by dragging the Result frame wider). I can't verify for sure this is what you're seeing, but I did notice that.

Comment: Of course... If you *did* want to syndicate this to other headers, you could replace the `Filter` value on the button with an image from the Glyphicons included with Bootstrap or whatever else you're using. This would solve the problem of having variability in the width of the button, which is the only real issue with what I have above.

Comment: Yeah I was trying trying to avoid giving it a static width. I guess that's the only way. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: jsFiddle came back, so take a look at the same fiddle sans the right three *width-chewing* columns: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qeT6T/48/ Your dropdown looks great! So it's tied to the width of the dropdown's container.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qeT6T/49/ The problem is not tied to the `table`, it's just a factor of how it works. I like the simplicity and elegance of using the image, but it does seem like there's got to be a way to resolve it. It's just, how do you apply a width that's not implicit or explicit?

Comment: So a possible solution is to assign a static width to both the input and button. Next, assign the calculated width to the container. It's not the best solution but it keeps the padding consistent.

Comment: Yes, that's an imperative solution, *ipso facto* if you will. Not necessarily responsive, right? I'm looking to see if there's a mo' better way. Also, if you think this is a good answer, hit the upvote button next to it, and mark this or another as the best answer when you have one by clicking the outlined checkmark as well. Note, you can only have one accepted answer per question.

Comment: I'm seeing dropdowns on the Bootstrap docs example pages that don't do take the width of the containing element, so I'm trying to narrow down what part of your markup or CSS is introducing the issue.

Comment: Well, I shoulda known. My very *first* thought was about `whites-space`. I'll blame the distraction of seeing those elements `display: block` for knocking me off target... `;)` Anyhow, put `white-space: nowrap` on the `.dropdown-menu li` and it works beautifully. See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qeT6T/55/

Answer (score 0):

This might be too quick and dirty for an overall solution, but how about 
adding this to your css:

```
.table .input-append {
   width: 300px;
}
```

example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/VeMBq/1/

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the only way to fix it.